# For security reasons should the default IP address of a router be changed?

Tags: networking, router, virus

Most routers have a factory-default IP address (e.g. 192.168.1.1 for Linksys), and that IP address is used to set up your router. Is there any advantage to be gained by changing this default IP to something else?  (I wonder if the VPNFilter hack didn't partially rely on the default IP by infecting any routers it could reach with that IP.)

Comment: DHCP will give anyone (including the bad guys) connecting to your network the router LAN address as part of the host configuration.

Comment: @Ramhound, some of the other possible IP configurations are 10.0.0.0-10.255.255.255; 172.16.0.0.-172.31.255.255; and 192.168.0.0-192.168.5.100, at least according to https://www.linksys.com/us/support-article?articleNum=142466.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your WiFi is correctly setup for security (disable **WPS**, change the **default password** and enable **WPA2** encryption) or you can't easily plug a computer in your network, **no**.

Keep note, the goal to change it is more if someday you do a VPN to another network. If you have the same network than the remote place it will bring **routing** problem. Changing the default IP come handy in such case.

Comment: I wanted to add this (and some other tips) because with WPS on, the WPS pin can be **calculated** using the MAC address of the router and it will allow **unauthorized people** to connect to your network. Own experience.

Comment: @Tiago: Experience with a specific model? While the WPS PIN is easily _bruteforceable_, many devices do generate it randomly.

Comment: Doesn't WPS require the user to click an icon in the router setup and then quickly (30 seconds or so) click the WPS button on the device being connected?

Comment: @billDOe, it's a flaw in WPS 1.x... Google WPSpixie attack if you are interested if your router is vunerable. It only takes on average a couple seconds to reveal a full WPA2 PSK

Comment: @grawity The 2 major ISP's in Portugal until end-2017 offered outdated routers ([NOS proprietary router](https://www.nos.pt/particulares/ajuda/equipamentos-servicos/internet/internet-fixa/Documents/NEW_Manual_RouterWiFi.pdf) and [MEO Technicolor TG784v3](https://conteudos.meo.pt/meo/Documentos/Manuais/Routers/Manual-Router-TG784nv3.pdf) and my own router is exploited with a simple app called WPS Connect on my Android. Not sure if it's fixed in the latest routers (because I have to upgrade my contract). I tested it with my friends on their routers and most are expoitable.